# Running multiple commands in multiple prompts from batch

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

I currently have three batch files and am trying to combine the functionality into one.

```
run.bat
--------
start "" /min cmd /k first.bat
start "" /min cmd /k second.bat

first.bat
--------
call C:\Users\jh\python_environment\Scripts\activate.bat
coilmq

second.bat
--------
call C:\Users\jh\python_environment\Scripts\activate.bat
python "C:\Users\jh\run\main.py"
```

So I execute run.bat to get what I want. That opens two command windows, with the respective commands run in each one and then they are minimized. How can I combine all this functionality into one bat script?

Answer (score 2):

`run.bat`

```
if not "%~1"=="" goto %1
start "" /min cmd /k "%~0" first
start "" /min cmd /k "%~0" second
goto :EOF

:first
call C:\Users\jh\python_environment\Scripts\activate.bat
coilmq
goto :EOF

:second
call C:\Users\jh\python_environment\Scripts\activate.bat
python "C:\Users\jh\run\main.py"
goto :EOF
```